# Discrete Mathematics Probability Lottery Ticket Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have seen a similar question posted (basically the same). However, I would like to know how this question would be approached if at least two of the numbers on the lottery ticket are among those drawn from the bin rather than 1. Also, why is it that we choose k from n-k if none is chosen? Is it because k could represent any positive integer?

Suppose that you buy a lottery ticket containing k distinct numbers from among{1,2,...,n}where 1≤k ≤n. To determine the winning ticket, k balls are randomly drawn without replacement from a bin containing n balls numbered 1,2,...,n. What is the probability that at least two of the numbers on your lottery ticket is among those drawn from the bin?

Answer (score 1):

To make matters easier to visualize, buy your ticket before the winning numbers are selected.  Without loss of generality, let your numbers selected be $1,2,\dots,k$.  (*It doesn't actually matter what your numbers are, the calculations will be the same*).

We have then $k$ "*good*" numbers and we have $n-k$ "*bad*" numbers that might have been selected when the winning numbers are drawn.

Now, to continue we can look at the probability that you *failed* to get at least two matching numbers.  That would occur when you either get exactly zero matching numbers or you get exactly one matching number.

In the case of getting zero matching numbers, that means $0$ of the numbers were good and the remaining $k$ numbers were all bad.  Pick which $k$ numbers were chosen out of the $n-k$ "*bad*" numbers to have drawn from.  There are $\binom{n-k}{k}$ ways of doing this.  This is out of the $\binom{n}{k}$ possible selections of $k$ numbers from all available numbers good and bad.

In the case of getting one matching number, that means $1$ of the numbers was good and the remaining $k-1$ numbers were all bad.  Pick which one good number was chosen in $\binom{k}{1}$ ways and which $k-1$ bad numbers were chosen in $\binom{n-k}{k-1}$ ways.  This gives a total of $\binom{k}{1}\binom{n-k}{k-1}$ combined ways to have chosen one good and $k-1$ bad numbers out of the $\binom{n}{k}$ possible selections of $k$ numbers from all available numbers good and bad.

We get then the probability of having matched at least two is:

$$1 - \dfrac{\binom{n-k}{k}+\binom{k}{1}\binom{n-k}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}$$

---

Note: in general given $N$ total objects, $K$ of which are good and the remaining $N-K$ of which are bad, when randomly selecting a subset of $n$ of the objects without repetition the probability of getting exactly $k$ good objects will be:

$$\dfrac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

This is the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution)

---

"*Why is it that we choose $k$ from $n-k$ if none is chosen?*"  Because there are $n-k$ bad objects and we wanted to pick which $k$ bad numbers were chosen from that collection of $n-k$ bad objects.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What is the *number* of ways that zero or one number matches? For zero matches, this is $\binom{n-k}k$, since the selection needs to choose its $k$ numbers from the $n-k$ numbers you didn't select. For one match, it is $k\binom{n-k}{k-1}$, since any of the $k$ balls you selected can be the match and the remaining $k-1$ balls must ne drawn from the same $n-k$ numbers not in your selection.

We get a probability of
$$1-\frac{\binom{n-k}k+k\binom{n-k}{k-1}}{\binom nk}$$